# remove disabled javascript warning bar in adobe acrobat

Tags: javascript, adobe, warnings, acrobat

Here's the deal, it's just an annoyance, but I'd rather not have to put up with annoyances.

Javascript is disabled in the reader, but every time I open a PDF with JS, I get that nasty, really unnecessary, warning at the top of the document.

I know it's merely telling me that the document may not be fully "functional" with the JS disabled, but I don't care, if someone can't write a document that gracefully fails with JS disabled, then it's not a document worth reading.

So, is there a means to globally dismiss or remove the warning that appears at the top of the document when I open a PDF with JS?

Comment: Make an according feature request at Adobe!

Comment: "if someone can't write a document that gracefully fails with JS disabled, then it's not a document worth reading." As a creator of PDF applications, I highly reset that remark. It says more about the writer than the fact.

Comment: My apologies for that, didn't mean it quite how it came out, and I was dealing with a bit of frustration over the issue at the time. BTW: Not sure I can reset that remark, but I do understand if you resent it. ;-)

Comment: Well, let's have a virtual beer, and things are settled. In fact, it is best practice to set up a document/form for a dumb PDF viewer, and use JavaScript to activate the smart parts. This will, however, not protect against deactivated JavaScript in Acrobat/Reader; here you will always get some kind of reminder (how obnoxious it is depends on the version).